# Properties of relations proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, relations

Im practicing some properties of relations and I cant seem to figure out one particular question. It follows

```
Consider the relation R on Z+(positive integers) as: For all m,n belonging to Z+, mRn means m|n. 
Is R reflexsive, symmetric or transitive?
Provide a complete proof or counterexample for each property.
You may only use the definition of divides
```

The definition of divides is as follows according to my particular textbook.

```
let n,d ∈ ℤ+ and d≠0.
n is divisible by d if and only if ∃ k ∈ ℤ such that n = dk
```

How would I go about solving this? Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Exactly *where* did you get stuck while trying to prove that it is reflexive? Or symmetric? Or transitive?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos If im being honest, im having difficulty understanding what the question is even asking so I would say im lost on all three parts

Comment: So the first thing I’d ask is, do you know what those terms mean? If you’re not sure, then start there, because you can’t prove a relation is “insert term” if you don’t know what “insert term” means.  If you do know what those terms mean, then your difficulty may be in how to prove things mathematically, which many people on here will be happy to describe in detail, if that’s your difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing but a matter of exloiting the definition. Since the relation is in words '$m$ divides $n$' it's clear from start that it will be reflexive, transitive but not symmetric.

Indeed $m\mid m$ since $m=1\cdot m$ and so the definition applies

For the transitivity: from $m\mid n$ and $n\mid p$ we have that $n=m\cdot k$, $ p=n\cdot l$. Combining the two we have
$$p=n\cdot l=m\cdot k\cdot l\implies m\mid p$$

Symmetry is wrong: $2\mid 4$ but $4\not\mid 2$.